# Check if a cell value is found in a column where cells may have multiple values then return a third cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I am trying to check whether the value in each cell within Column A is in Column D. Some cells in Column D have multiple values within a single cell. If the value of Column A IS found in Column D then I want the formula to return what's in Column B (value next to Column A that matched).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,$D$2:$D$5))))>0,B2,"")
```

Drag down..

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would reverse this search so I search from Column D (some cells have multiple numbers) and if it matches with Column A then return the value of column B? I have over 5000 rows in Excel and am not able to make the cells with multiple numbers into their own row unfortunately otherwise that would make it much more simple.

Comment: Yes it's possible, I see by now you have opened another question. Let me answer that one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at just row by row analysis then try this:

```
=if(iserror(search(a2,d2)),"",b2)
```

if you are trying to match any row in D then I suggest breaking out all items in D into an item per row and then doing a VLOOKUP

Comment: OP wants to search whole of column D I believe.

Comment: i think he just wants row looked at

Comment: I want to search whole of column D

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy column B to Column E? If so,

=Vlookup("*" & A1 & "*", D:E, 2,0) and scroll down.

If not, a similar index(match( function will work with a wild card. (*)