# Return a third cell value at the location of another cell if two other cells match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJAS0.png (Sorry for the link, I don't have enough rep to post an image)

I'm trying to get a formula where if any of the values found in column D (taking into account that some cells have multiple values ie. cell D4) match a value in Column A then return the value of the same row associated with Column D.

For example, in cell D4 the number 786403213972 matches A2 then cell C4 will return 100.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on your last question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56977453/check-if-a-cell-value-is-found-in-a-column-where-cells-may-have-multiple-values/56977676?noredirect=1#comment100493718_56977676), hereby a way to do this (beware, it's long and tricky)

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(D2,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(D2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2,CHAR(10),""))+1))-1)*99+((ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(D2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2,CHAR(10),""))+1)))=1),99)),TRANSPOSE($A$2:$A$7)))))>0,B2,"")
```

Confirm as array formula through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down...